# Advantage Database Server: in-memory queries

Tags: memory-management, advantage-database-server

As far as I know, ADS v.10 tries to keep result of query in memory until it is a quite huge. The same should be true for the __output table and for temporary tables. When the result becoming large, swapping stated.

The question is what memory limit is set for a query, a worker, whatever? Could this limit be configured?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The overall limit is controlled by the [MAX_CACHE_MEMORY](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage9.1/max_cache_memory.htm) configuration parameter.  I don't think there is currently any configuration parameter or mechanism to control it on a per-user basis.

In general, an LRU scheme is used to remove old pages when the limit is reached.  In addition, it uses a scaling algorithm to control how much memory each user can get to avoid allowing one connection to constantly be acquiring overly large portions of the cache.